# angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

The following Angular js code throws the error-

> "angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined" for the code-

HelloWorld.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="module1">
    <head>
        <title>My First Custom Directive</title>
        <script src="../angular.js"></script>
        <script src="helloworldDirective.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hello-world></hello-world>
    </body>
    </html>
```

helloWorldDirective.js-

```
(function() {
    
    var module1=angular.module('module1',[]);
    module1.directive('helloWorld',function(){
        return
        {
            template:'Hello Somesh!!Keep it up.'
        };
        
    });
    
    
}());
```

But when I replace the Javascript file with the following code it works:

```
(function() {
    
    var module1=angular.module('module1',[]);
    var helloWorld=function()
{
var directive={};     
directive.template='Hello Somesh!!Keep it up.';
return directive;
}
module1.directive('helloWorld',helloWorld);
    
}());
```

Both codes are doing basically the same thing but one is failing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's Automatic Semicolon Injection turns this:

```
  return
        {
            template:'Hello Somesh!!Keep it up.'
        };
```

into this:

```
  return;
        {
            template:'Hello Somesh!!Keep it up.'
        };
```

a return, followed by a useless code block.  (The `template:` is treated as a label.)

Debugging hint:  JSHint or JSLint would have found this error for you.

Style hint: In JavaScript, always keep open braces on the same line... though only the `return` and `throw` statement are affect by this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, there is an *"unreachable code error"*.

You can fix this error with:

```
return template = {template: 'Hello Somesh!!Keep it up.'};
```

Else you can't get the pointer to the attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry: first your first example didn't work, now it does.      The only difference: I put the whole thing in one line and set a whitespace between colon and quotation, so its just leike above, but without the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to define your directives:

```
 app.directive('helloWorld', [function () {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       transclude: false,
       template: 'Hello Somesh!!Keep it up.'
    }
}]);
```